# StandardValueSet: adding picklist values to case status field

Tags: deployment

I added picklist values to case status field by creating

**CaseStatus.StandardValueSet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Active</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Active</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Closed</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Closed</label>
        <closed>true</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Enrolled</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Enrolled</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>New</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
        <label>New</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Pending Closure</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Pending Closure</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Pending Enrollment</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Pending Enrollment</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

and I did push that by using ant migration tool and it deployed to salesforce successfully.

Here my question is once I did push the values which already there is the salesforce org deactivating automatically and adding my new values to case status field.

Can some one please help me how to restrict the picklist values to not deactivate automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a `standardValueSet`, you are deploying the entire picklist for that standard field. As such, SFDC decides that any picklist items in the target org *NOT IN* the deployment package are automatically made inactive.

Thus, to preserve old standard value set values, you need to include those in the deployment along with any new standard value set values

From the [Metadata API doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_special_behavior.htm) V46

> Picklist Values
>
> Values for a picklist field in a target org that are
>   not included in the metadata are set to inactive. For example, if the
>   target org has a picklist that includes an active value of 1, and the
>   metadata does not include 1 as a value for the picklist, 1 changes
>   from active to inactive in the target org.

Comment: Is there any other way to deploy custom picklist values to case status field other than using standardValueSet.

Comment: @user70297 - Case.Status is an OOTB field (picklist) and StandardValueSet is how that picklist is defined; see [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm?search_text=standardvalueset)